# What happens neurologically and chemically when an individual is confused?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience

For example, trying to understand a mathematical problem and its solution, or abstract reasoning, but in the process get lost even have no clear idea of what part is 'not understood'

Comment: This question is far too broad. Adding your own research and providing context is essential.

Comment: I agree with that it's broad, but what if they couldn't find any thing on that? Would that still be closed?